# Как заблокировать Ctrl + Alt + Del в Python?

Tags: python

Задача проста, нужно заблокировать данное сочетание клавишь, и всё; Пробывал keyboard либу, и да она блокирует нажатие Ctrl Alt и прочих клавишь, и даже сочетания их, но не блокирует именно сочитание Ctrl+Alt+Del.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак, потому что для Windows это важный пункт для защиты пользователя, эта команда будет исполняться в любом случае, кроме полной блокировки клавиатуры.

Comment: При условии, что ему хватит памяти...

Answer (score 1):

Есть способ, но только для блокировки самого диспетчера, если кому нужно будет, это пакет elevate, имеющий одноименную функцию, которая просто запрашивает у пользователя права админа, и после прописать команду на отключение диспетчера в реестре через командную строку, вот финальный код:

```
elevate()
os.system('REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /f /v "DisableTaskMgr" /t REG_DWORD /d 1')
```